# php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I recently setup a server using the latest version of XAMPP for Windows. With it came PHP 5.3.  I'm now looking for a memcache.dll file that works with PHP 5.3  I've used some of the previous .dll files and recieved an error message:

"PHP Startup: memcache: Unable t initialize module.
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP compiled with module api=20090626
These options need to match"

Any links to a PHP 5.3 memcache.dll file would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21):

If you are using php 5.3 from within xampp 1.7.2/1.7.3, this distribution works fine:

http://shikii.net/blog/downloads/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip

It's a real pity that windows.php.net is still not up yet with PECL windows binaries.

Answer (score 9):

Links are not working any more. But you can use following SVN repository to download the file.

http://zhiliansns.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/software/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip

Comment: +1 thanks for the link. About the only working link on the interweb!

Comment: Is there one for memcache**d** built with vc6 for PHP5.3?

Comment: Link require a password now... :(

Answer (score 7):

There are compiled extension available from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Amongst those, you'll find :

- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip (2009-07-03 05:30 -0700)
- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC9-x64.zip (2009-07-03 05:45 -0700)
- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC9-x86.zip (2009-07-03 06:11 -0700)
- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-nts-VC6-x86.zip (2009-07-03 05:29 -0700)
- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-nts-VC9-x64.zip (2009-07-03 05:35 -0700)
- php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-nts-VC9-x86.zip (2009-07-03 06:07 -0700)

Depending on the version of PHP 5.3 you are using, one of those might do ;-)

If you don't know which one you should choose, take a look at the "Which version do I choose?" block on the left of http://windows.php.net/ (quoting) :

> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or
>   Apache2 from apache.org you need to
>   use the VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you
>   should use the VC9 versions of PHP
>
> VC6 Versions are compiled with the
>   legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler
>
> VC9 Versions are compiled with the
>   Visual Studio 2008 compiler and have
>   improvements in performance and
>   stability. The VC9 versions require
>   you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++
>   Runtime (x86) or the Microsoft 2008
>   C++ Runtime (x64) installed
>
> Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org
>   binaries

Maybe one day, extensions will be on this site too *(as pecl4win is down)*... Would be nice, actually ^^

Comment: Is there a client binary for memcache**d** built with vc6 for PHP5.3?

Comment: I had a Wamp 2.2 with PHP 5.3 ts on Windows 8. i used the php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC9-x86 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Found this blog which has a PHP 5.3 version that worked for me:

http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

You should download this extension from code.google.com:

[php client for php 5.3(VC6) in xampp](http://code.google.com/p/sirius/downloads/detail?name=php_memcache.dll)

Answer (score 1):

I have php 5.3.13 and in my case the link which seven provided didn't work. But this one did: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-vc9-x86.zip