# php_memcache.dll for zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, xampp, zend-framework2

recently setup a server using the latest version of XAMPP for Windows. With it came zf2. I'm now looking for a memcache.dll file that works with PHP 5.3 I've used some of the previous .dll files and recieved an error message:

```
"PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module.
Module compiled with build ID=API20090206,TS,vc6
PHP compiled with build ID=API20090206,TS,vc9
These options need to match"
```

This error is the solution?Anxious.

Thanks for the help!
Another not understand the master of the Chinese?

Comment: Does not understand Chinese?English was not very good, please forgive.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for download: [php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511045/php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-3)

There's a couple links on the side you know.