# windows - php_memcache.dll - for PHP 5.4

Tags: php, windows, dll, memcached

I am borrowing the similar thread that wasn't helpfull for me:
[php_memcache.dll for PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511045/php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-3)

I setup a server using the latest version of easyPHP for Windows. With it came PHP 5.4. I'm now looking for a memcache.dll file that worked for me before and I get this error

"PHP Startup: memcache: Unable t initialize module.
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module api=20100525
These options need to match"

Any links to a PHP 5.4 memcache.dll file would be greatly appreciated.

In the mentioned thread they adressed version for 5.3 and pierre, but there I find only an older version of the dll

Comment: nope.... I did revert to the old one and waiting to upgrade once it is out

Comment: i'm a linux user, i don't know if this works but you can try it: http://hashcode.ru/questions/86695/php-5-4-windows-memcache

Comment: @DS_web_developer : did you check my answer ?

Comment: no, sorry. I've ended up on 5.3 and for now I am not planning to update. But whren I do, I know where to check ;) Thanx!

Comment: have you been able to fine a working version ??

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found this link and it worked for me:

[php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip)

Or you can browse a list of the latest releases here and find an applicable version:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/

Comment: Links can rot! Please describe your amswer briefly

Comment: I am giving you an upvote because this IS working windows memcache extension compiled for php 5.4.x and VC9. exactly what original question asked for, and much better solution than statically compiled version of php with memcache extension.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka You mean like edit the question and add the base64 of the DLL? I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: Page can be found -- apache started with this perfectly.

Comment: Using XAMPP 1.8.1 (Compiler MSVC9 Visual C++ 2008) on Windows 8.
Followed your link http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/ . This version works for me: [php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip)

Comment: what's the difference between ts and nts release? you can find both in here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/ and both are for VC9

Comment: This one worked for me php_memcache-3.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip

Answer (score 13):

I found out this:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/memcache/3.0.6/

Try the following if the above fails:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sjkuotlz2sl1kpc/v7-QZeFxHR

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching a version for my PHP 5.4 TS. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between `nts` and `ts` in the name of the downloadable file?

Comment: NTS = non thread safe, TS = Thread safe. If you run phpinfo on your server, you can see which one you should use by looking at the Thread Safety value. If it says Disabled, use NTS.

Comment: Thank you. May want to edit that fropbox link as we can all see pictures of you...

Answer (score 5):

The link is dead try
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/

You'll find the latest memcache dll release in there. What you need to know before downloading:

-The OS version (32 or 64 bit)

-The PHP Compiler version

-Thread Safe support

The PHP Compiler version and thread safe support can be easily checked using the phpinfo() function

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Kevin Horst, tested and working on my Win7 box !

**The solution :**  just download the [statically compiled version](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-5.4.0-Win32-VC9-x86.zip) hosted on Amazon AWS, and extract.

Here is some output from `php -i` :

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.0

System => Windows NT xxxx 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date => Mar  7 2012 14:17:27
Compiler => MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture => x86
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-cli" "--enable-memcache=shared"
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\UniServer\usr\local\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,TS,VC9
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,TS,VC9

memcache

memcache support => enabled
Active persistent connections => 0
Version => 2.2.5
Revision => $Revision: 319585 $
```

Comment: Do you mean just to replace your php directory with that file? Because that doesn't have memcache.dll in it...

Comment: It's statically linked, not dynamically. Thus no .dll.

Answer (score 2):

Any pecl modules that have officially been compiled for windows you find under http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

- You need to know what php version you are running ie: 5.3,5.4,5.5 and so on
- You need to know if your php version is 32 or 64 ie  x86, x64
- You need to know if the php version was compiled as thread safe or not ie:ts,nts

All the information you can get from a file with the following content

```
    <?php phpinfo()
```

and view it from the webserver
or from the command line sending the output to a file with:

```
    php -i > phpinfo.txt
```

NOTE: from the command line you get the data for php-cli witch most likely was compiled with the same configuration

And note that there is Memcache and Memcached but from the php website only memcache is available