# Memcache extension for php - xampp windows not working

Tags: php, memcached, xampp, php-extension

I have winginx on my windows machine which comes with memcached server and module. I have it running on port 11211. I have xampp on my machine as well and I need to connect to the memcached server through xampp. I used [this](http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7) tutorial to add the php_memcache extension to my php-xampp. Also, referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347743/windows-php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-4) at stackoverflow. I have xampp version 1.7.4 with PHP 5.3.5 (VC6 X86 32bit).

I still get the error "class Memcache not found" or "call to undefined function memcache_connect()".
Is there a problem with the php_memcache dll I am using - I have tried both x86 and 64 bit versions?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First: Check that memcache apear in php_info();

Comment: Make sure you're using the right extension: PHP has `memcache` and `memcached`, check phpinfo() to see which is actually enabled

Comment: Actually, neither is enabled. memcache does not appear in phpinfo. I am using the memcache dll build from vc9 and php from vc6, will that be a problem ?

Comment: Check the apache log from when you restarted the server, it should indicate if there's a problem with the php_memcache.dll file

Comment: You are right. The log helped me figure out the problem. I have solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the compiler versions mismatch(I had vc6 for php and memcache was build from vc9). One of the posts from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/adKBLzNe2to) discussion states php has dropped support for vc6, so I reinstalled xampp which had php 5.4 with vc9. Used the memcache dll in http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.6/php_memcache-3.0.6-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip and everythin worked fine!

Thanks for the help.