# Getting a warning "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library"

Tags: php, memcached, wamp

I have setup memcache to work on windows and downloaded the php_memcache.dll file. But now whenever i start my wamp server it shown me a warning as:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

"C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_memcache.dll" - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

What does this warning means.? How can i correct it.

I am working with Windows 7(64bit).

Comment: Where did you get your memcache.dll from? This would seem as if you got a version that does not fit your specs.  Have yo been to http://windows.php.net/ to find the right package?

Comment: answer and link for download: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347743/windows-php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-4)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the visual C (VC) version used for building your PHP, be sure to use the same version for the php_memcache.dll (its usually in the name of the archive you get from php.net - i.e. php_blah_blah_VC9_.zip)

No need to build it yourself, you can check the net for build with the same C and the same PHP version.

Answer (score -1):

You may have an issue with your a copy of php_memcache.dll. Try utilizing this file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/uq6srb