# Error trying to use memcache is with php 5.5?

Tags: php, xampp, memcached

I am trying to use memcached with php 5.5, is it possible?

I have downloaded `php_memcache.dll` and put it inside the `php/ext/` folder and also added a new line of code in side php.ini `extension=php_memcache.dll`. But still it is not working.

When I try to call `$memcache = new Memcache;` the following occurs.

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rnd\memcache\index.php on line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating an php_info page to check if the module is loaded.

info.php

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

ref: http://www.phpinfofile.com/

I'm using PHP 5.5.9 and memcache works fine. Note that i'm using a *nix machine though.

```
memcache

memcache support => enabled
Active persistent connections => 0
Version => 2.2.7
Revision => $Revision: 327750 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 8192 => 8192
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms => 1000 => 1000
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => standard => standard
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
```

Comment: I have got an error `"PHP Startup: memcache: Unable t initialize module. Module compiled with module API=20090626 PHP compiled with module api=20100525 These options need to match"` when i restart the apache.

Comment: are you using WAMPP? XAMPP? or from binary?

Comment: Then i recommend you to get your answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347743/windows-php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-4. You can get a 5.5 version from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8.