# php_memcache.dll for php 5.2.4

Tags: php, windows, dll, memcached

Trying to find the dll for memcache on php 5.2.4.  Running on windows server 2k3 x64

I can find some for 5.3, but either they don't work or I cannot figure out how to get them to work. The php.ini file points to the right extension name in the ext file, but it fails with the error:

Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in \PATH\ on line 2

This error occurs with or without the php_memcache.dll for php 5.3 in the ext folder.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Why not compile it yourself? Or update to 5.3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511045/php-memcache-dll-for-php-5-3

Comment: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.4-Win32.zip

The version in that zip was compiled for 5.2.4, whether it will work on x64 I don't know.

http://www.php.net/releases/ is always the place to start when looking for old stuff, and it's where I found that link. But I would suggest that an upgrade to 5.3 or 5.4 would be in order, or at the very least an upgrade to 5.2.17.